# Python RegEx for match + string until next found match

Tags: python, regex

I have an export from the database which is containing product data. The separation for each product is done using comma, but some product names are also containing comma.

So we are ending up with a mess like:

```
13371337:Bat,TH,Li-Met,Blub,9.5V,370mAHr,1/2_AA-Cell,50pcs,13351234:Radio - Antenna 2.4 GHz AB/C midi (10p),15642345:Board SMB - Some Magic Board,95653345:Board SMK 6 - Some Magic Knobs - Mod6,56735632:Control Unit Z65 - Mod9
```

I would need a regex which is splitting to:

```
13371337:Bat,TH,Li-Met,Blub,9.5V,370mAHr,1/2_AA-Cell,50pcs

13351234:Radio - Antenna 2.4 GHz AB/C midi (10p)

15642345:Board SMB - Some Magic Board

95653345:Board SMK 6 - Some Magic Knobs - Mod6

56735632:Control Unit Z65 - Mod9
```

I ended up with a regex `[0-9]{5,9}` , which is separating fine the product numbers.

Then I tried: `[0-9]{5,9}[^@]+` , which is only partially matching the first string, due to the additional commas.

Is there any way to include as well the following string as shown above?

Comment: Try replacing on `(?<!^)\b[0-9]{5,9}:` and replace with `\n\g<0>` See https://regex101.com/r/6rrJQh/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Rather `(?<!^)\b(?=[0-9]{5,9}:)`. `re.split(r'(?<!^)\b(?=[0-9]{5,9}:)', text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes you can also do that of course

Comment: Cant you specify other custom delimitator on data extraction?

Comment: @Wonka: No I can't because this export function is used as an import for other functions. I'm the only one having this issue.

Comment: @Aptivskorb something meant to output CSV giving it without proper escaping is obviously lacking and its best to fix it rather than accomodating in other places. Also adding proper escaping to the output won't break things for anyone else unless they are already facing the same problem.

Comment: Or `re.findall(r"\b[0-9]{5,9}:.*?(?=,\b[0-9]{5,9}:|$)", text)`

Comment: @Aptivskorb we dont know you code for extraction, but for sure you can pass extra argument to the function and use other delimitator

Comment: @Wonka you are totally right. If I would be the developer of the output this is what I would have done as well.
BUT: I am not the responsible dev and the change could potentially impact too many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `[0-9]{5,9}[^@]+` that you tried matches 5-9 digits followed by 1 or more characters other than an `@` char (which can also match digits and there is no `@` char in the example data)

---

You can make the regex more specific by applying a word boundary to the start, and match the colon after the digits.

Use that as the start of the match, and then match as least as possible characters until the next occurrence of that pattern, or assert the end of the string in case of the last occurrence.

```
\b[0-9]{5,9}:.*?(?=,\b[0-9]{5,9}:|$)
```

See the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/Isap8J/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qstjjW).

```
import re

s = "13371337:Bat,TH,Li-Met,Blub,9.5V,370mAHr,1/2_AA-Cell,50pcs,13351234:Radio - Antenna 2.4 GHz AB/C midi (10p),15642345:Board SMB - Some Magic Board,95653345:Board SMK 6 - Some Magic Knobs - Mod6,56735632:Control Unit Z65 - Mod9"
pattern = r"\b[0-9]{5,9}:.*?(?=,\b[0-9]{5,9}:|$)"
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(result)
```

If you must use re.split, you can start the pattern again with a word boundary and assert not the start of the string to the left. This will prevent matching a position right before the first occurrence which will, when splitting, return an empty entry in the resulting list.

Then assert the part of the pattern that starts all the separate parts (as suggested in the comments by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)) and that will give you the position to split on.

See the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/Jje2Sy/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F6SzJh).

```
pattern = r"\b(?<!^)(?=[0-9]{5,9}:)"
result = re.split(pattern, s)
print(result)
```

Both code examples will output:

Output

```
[
 '13371337:Bat,TH,Li-Met,Blub,9.5V,370mAHr,1/2_AA-Cell,50pcs',
 '13351234:Radio - Antenna 2.4 GHz AB/C midi (10p)',
 '15642345:Board SMB - Some Magic Board',
 '95653345:Board SMK 6 - Some Magic Knobs - Mod6',
 '56735632:Control Unit Z65 - Mod9'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The data string must be splitted in positions where there is a comma, followed by several digits ending with a colon: `,(?=\d+:)`. This regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
,      ','
--------------------------------------------------
(?=    look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------
  \d+    digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
         the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------
  :      ':'
--------------------------------------------------
)      end of look-ahead
```

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

data='13371337:Bat,TH,Li-Met,Blub,9.5V,370mAHr,1/2_AA-Cell,50pcs,\
13351234:Radio - Antenna 2.4 GHz AB/C midi (10p),\
15642345:Board SMB - Some Magic Board,\
95653345:Board SMK 6 - Some Magic Knobs - Mod6,\
56735632:Control Unit Z65 - Mod9'

pprint(re.split(r',(?=\d+:)', data))
```

Output.

```
['13371337:Bat,TH,Li-Met,Blub,9.5V,370mAHr,1/2_AA-Cell,50pcs',
 '13351234:Radio - Antenna 2.4 GHz AB/C midi (10p)',
 '15642345:Board SMB - Some Magic Board',
 '95653345:Board SMK 6 - Some Magic Knobs - Mod6',
 '56735632:Control Unit Z65 - Mod9']
```